# signin-oidc callback 404 with URL Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, identityserver4, openid-connect, arr

I configured URL Rewrite and added entry to hosts file to access https://localhost/app as https://app.localhost.

The issue I got stuck with is openid connect callback after successful sign-in on identity server 4. It returns 404 error.
And it's logical as in client's startup RedirectUri value is set to https://app.localhost/signin-oidc but when callback is coming from Identity Server url rewrite rule transforms it to https://localhost/app/signin-oidc

How to make it work with URL rewrite? appreciate any help and ideas

P.S. ARR proxy is enabled but Reverse rewrite host is unchecked(It was solution for similar issues but it didn't help in my case)

Comment: you need to make a special case for the url signin-oidc or if it's hosted where it's going just change the config of your client to match the final url.

Comment: @cheesemacfly if I change config to final url it generates(https://localhost/app/signin-oidc) identity server returns "Invalid redirect_uri" error

Comment: Did you change it to the same value on both the client and server settings?

Comment: @cheesemacfly ofc. But I was wrong in prev comment. It throws another error that is regarding nonce cookie - RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null. I think it's because there's no nonce cookie for localhost/app but for app.localhost

Comment: that's probably what's happening. You'll have to find a way of sharing a session or something that holds the nonce and state between the 2 domains.